# Magento 1.9/1.4: sending email with attachment using core/email_queue

Tags: magento-1.9, email, magento-1.4, email-queue

I wish to send email with an attachemnt, and I must use core/email_queue. How can I add attachment to the email?

There are a lot of anwers on how to adding attachment using core/email_template, but this is what I'm after.

Comment: Can you update your code where you want this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: sending attachments is simply not supported by the core/email_queue. Using the queue with attachments would require a major re-implementation.